# Get image from UIView with no parent view

Tags: ios, uiview

I have a `UIView` that is composed of other subviews.

This `UIView` is not a subview of any other views in the app.

Can I get an image (`UIImage`) from this `UIView`? Or should it be referenced from a displayed view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to have it displayed. 
Just pass that view object to this function and you would get the image

```
+ (UIImage *) imageWithView:(UIView *)view
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, view.opaque, 0.0);
    [view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

    UIImage * img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return img;
}
```

Comment: I've realized that after posting the question with half an Hour.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
func imageWithView (view: UIView)->UIImage
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, false, 0.0)
    view.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext())
    newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return newImage
}
```

This is the `swift` version